# -webkit-box-orient: vertical; in sass is not compiled in gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp

In sass file

```
h3 {
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                display: -webkit-box;
                line-height: 24px; 
                max-height: 24px;
                -webkit-line-clamp: 1; 
                -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            }
```

After running gulp task, getting in css as

```
 .article-list.search .article-listings__item h3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 24px;
  max-height: 24px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
}
```

The style `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` is missing in css file.

My gulp task for sass compilation is

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('src/assets/stylesheets/index.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

Comment: sass version used is gulp-ruby-sass: 2.1.1

Answer (score 15):

Add this line of code and it will work fine:

```
/* autoprefixer: off */

-webkit-box-orient: vertical;

/* autoprefixer: on */
```

Answer (score 2):

Look this issus on [Github](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/776).

config autoprefixer like this. Hope it can help you.

```
autoprefixer({
  remove: false,
  browsers: ['last 2 versions']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also capitalize the first letter of the prefix.
It will avoid the autoprefixer from modifying the code.

```
-Webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

This code works because CSS is case insensitive.